# How to send data to the input in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, gps

can i ask a question. I try to make a reading GPS ( the Latitude and Longitude ), i follow this link https://www.itilog.com/ but it just using innerHTMl or sthing. the idea is how to sending data ( the Latitude and Longitude ) into the input tag so that i can have the data the user who enter these data. Here are the code i follow W3school:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Displaying location using Latitude and Longitude</p>

<button class="geeks" onclick="getlocation()">
    Click Me
</button>
<input type="text" id="demo1" onkeyup="showLoc()"></input>


<script>
    var variable1 = document.getElementById("demo1");
    function getlocation() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showLoc);
    }
    function showLoc(pos) {
    variable1.innerInput =
        "Latitude: " +
        pos.coords.latitude +
        "<br>Longitude: " +
        pos.coords.longitude;
    }
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

I have the code in html and css:
#NOTE: U need to using responsive to see the code files
this is html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="generateqr.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h3>Course's name</h3>
        <div class="body">
            <div class="small_container">
                <button>Generate QR</button>
            </div>
            <div class="small_container">
                <button>Your Files</button>
            </div>
            <div class="info">
                <div class="title1">                
                    <p>Longitude:</p>
                    <input placeholder="type here...">
                </div>
                <div class="title2">
                    <p>Latitude:</p>
                    <input placeholder="type here...">
                </div>             
            </div>
            <div class="location">
                <a id="check" href="https://www.itilog.com/">check here if you don't know your location</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <a href="">Back</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and CSS file:

```css
* {
    background-color: #7879f1;
    position: relative;
}

h3 {
    text-align: center;
}

.body{
    width: 110%;
    height: 500px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
}

.small_container{
    background-color: white;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-top: 20%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.footer{
    margin-top: 515px;
    background-color: white;
    width: 110%;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-bottom: -20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;

}

button{
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

a{
    background-color: white;
    margin-left: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.info{
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    background-color: white;
    margin-top: 10%;
}

.input{
    background-color: white;
}

input {
    background-color: white;
}

p {
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 10%;
}

.location {
    margin-top: 20%;
    background-color: white;
}

.title1{
    background-color: white;
}

.title2{
    background-color: white;
}
```

i hope that we can send the data to the input ( i already have 2 input tag for the Latitude and Longitude )

Answer (score 0):

You can change inputs like that :

```
var input = document.getElementById("input");
input.value = 'value';
```

For your context i made a jsfidle for you understand how to do it :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Displaying location using Latitude and Longitude</p>

<button id="_button">
    Click Me
</button>
<input type="text" id="latitudeInput" value=""></input>
<input type="text" id="longitudeInput" value=""></input>


<script>
    var button = document.getElementById('_button');
    var latitudeInput = document.getElementById("latitudeInput");
    var longitudeInput = document.getElementById("longitudeInput");

    button.addEventListener('click', function(){
        getlocation();
    });

    function getlocation() {
        // Callbacks
            const successCallback = (position) => {
            // Set inputs values
            latitudeInput.value = position.coords.latitude;
            longitudeInput.value = position.coords.longitude;
            };
            // Manage error messages
            const errorCallback = (error) => {
            alert(error.code+' : '+error.message);
            };
        // Call
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, errorCallback);
    }

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

[jsfiddle.net/EdvaldoFilho/ermup5a9/4/](https://jsfiddle.net/EdvaldoFilho/ermup5a9/4/)

***Hope it helps you !***